# C# Can a dictionary<int, myobject> be converted into a list?

Tags: c#

let's assume this is my custom object

```
public class myObject
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Location {get;set;}
}
```

And I am returning a collection of `myObject` instances in a dictionary:

```
return new Dictionary<int, List<MyObject>>();
```

This collection is basically a list of my objects.  the key refers to the parent class's `Id` which has one to many relationship with `myObject` class.

What is the best way to create a list out of dictionary?

Instead of using `Dictionary<int, List<MyObject>>`, I am planning to use:

```
public class myObject
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Location {get;set;}
    public int ParentId {get;set;}**
}
```

and returning:

```
return new List<MyObject> myObjects();
```

what is your suggestion?

Comment: You should be able to do this with `SelectMany`...

Answer (score 4):

```
return myDict.Values.ToList();
```

You just need to get at the values, which is thankfully convenient.

EDIT:

Now that I understand a bit more of the problem, you want to set the Id field of each object to its key in the Dictionary (the parent id) before returning the list.

Well, first I would recommend that you simply set that property before adding it to the list in the first place.  However, if you can't do that (for some unfathomable reason) you can simply iterate through the Dictionary beforehand and set the property:

```
foreach( var pair in dict )
{
    foreach( var myObj in pari.Value )
    {
        myObj.Id = pair.Key;
    }
}

return dict.Values.ToList();
```

Let me know if I'm missing something fundamental to your problem here.

Comment: Not true; he wants to have the ParentId (which is the key in the dictionary I suppose) as a property in the instances that are in the list.

Comment: Ok, but it wouldn't change anything.  The Values have their own ID property, and that's how they are paired up in the dictionary.  If those are different then it's really a design problem and the ID should be assigned before they are added into the dictionary.

Comment: Yep, I want to use parentid in LINQ to find relevant my object objects

Comment: I still don't get it.  Why wouldn't you initialize them with the correct Id to begin with and then add them like so: `dict.Add( myObj.Id, myObj);`?

Comment: no no Ed.S.  The id is different for each MyObject.  Think of it as a primary key of a table.  And collection of MyObject is a value of the dictionary.  The key is an integer value which links a group of MyObject values in a dictionary.

Comment: Can I use LINQ incombination with myDict.Values.ToList() to assign value of ParentId as the key of the dictionary?

Comment: Well, a collection of `MyObject` is **not** the value in your example, it is a single instance of `MyObject`.  That changes the code.  I still don't see the issue; you need to set the parent Id on each MyObject before adding it or before returning the list.  That is as simple as a loop.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker:  Why do you have to use LINQ at all?  Just use a foreach loop and set the Id for each one using it's key in the dictionary.  That's what the LINQ equivalent would do anyway.

Comment: Your're right Ed.S.  I made a mistake in my above code.  It's Dictionary<int, List<MyObject> I need to convert that to a List<MyObject>

Comment: I don't think your problem description makes a lot of sense.  You can't have one to many from key to value because you don't have a `Dictionary<int, SomeCollection<MyObject>>`, you have a `Dictionary<int, MyObject>`.  Only one MyObject per key.

Comment: Great. If I was to write this in LINQ, what would be the neatest way to write it?

Comment: ok, I figured it out. Using Select() method of the List. which inside runs a loop.  Thanks for your help

Comment: I don't see why that matters.  I honestly think that a nested loop is 'neater' in this case than any LINQ expression you will come up with.  This solution is simple and it works, I don't understand the need to use LINQ at all.  Just because X language feature is new and shiny doesn't mean it is the best way to solve any problem. Also, I still think that the 'right' way to do it is to simply initialize the Id field with the parent Id before you add to the dictionary.  Then you don't have to do the manual update at all.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to put the keys or the values into the list?

For the keys, do:

```
return new List<int>(dict.Keys);
```

For the values (which I think is what you're looking for) do:

```
return new List<MyObject>(dict.Values);
```

If you want both, you can use a [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx), but you have to be using .NET 4.0 or higher.

```
List<Tuple<int, MyObject>> list = new List<Tuple<int, MyObject>>();
foreach (var i in dict.Keys) {
    list.Add(Tuple.Create(i, dict[i]));
}
return list;
```

Comment: i want both because i want to then find MyObject enteries which belong to the ParentId

Answer (score 0):

> This collection is basically a list of
>   my objects. the key refers to the
>   parent class's Id which has one to
>   many relationship with myObject class.

The key in the dictionary should be unique, so how can you create a one to many relationship in such case ?

Anyway, you'll first have to create a new class which is able to hold all the existing values, and the extra parentId:

```
        public class MyObject2
        {
            public MyObject2(int id, string name, string location, int parentId)
            {
                this.Id = id;
                this.Name = name;
                this.Location = location;
                this.ParentId = parentId;
            }

            public int Id
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
            public string Name
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
            public string Location
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

            public int ParentId
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return String.Format ("Id={0}; Name={1}; Location={2}; ParentId={3}", Id, Name, Location, ParentId);
            }
        }
```

Then, with a simple LINQ query, you can achieve what you want:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, myObject> ();
dict.Add(2, new myObject(1, "Test1", "Somewhere"));
dict.Add (1, new myObject (2, "Test2", "location"));

var result = dict.Select (kp => new MyObject2 (kp.Value.Id, kp.Value.Name, kp.Value.Location, kp.Key)).ToList ();

 foreach( var r in result )
 {
     Console.WriteLine (r.ToString ());
 }

 Console.ReadLine ();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the key to be the `ParentId` and the value to be all the instances of MyObject that have that parent, maybe a Dictionary isn't the best data structure. Maybe you want to use a [Lookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx), which is basically a Dictionary that can have multiple values for a single key. The (possible) downside being that a Lookup is read-only. You create it once, and then use it to, well, look things up. But you can't modify it later, only recreate it.

Given a list of all the instances of MyObject, you'd create a Lookup like this:

```
ILookup<int, MyObject> myLookup = allObjects.ToLookup(x => x.ParentId);
```

**Edit:**

I see from comments on another answer that you're actually starting with a `Dictionary<int, List<MyObject>>` (the moral equivalent of a Lookup) and you want to get a flattened list of all the instances of MyObject. This is actually an easy one-liner:

```
IEnumerable<MyObject> allObjects = dict.Values.SelectMany(x => x);
```